# Annotation ElementType

Tags: java, annotations

What does following annotation's ElementType means?

```
@Entity
@Table(table="application")
@ElementType(type=1L) 
class application extends Element
```

Comment: Language? Platform? Technology?

Comment: Can you post the import statements of the class?

Answer (score 2):

Please check: [ElementType](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html). It's an enum and all fields are defined there. You shouldn't rely on numeric values in your code.

Answer (score 0):

That's a literal of type `long` and value 1. What it means depends on the definition of the annotation, but most likely there are constants defined in the `ElementType` annotation class that you're supposed to use instead of long literals.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code compiles, there is a lot wrong with it. ElementType is an enum in the JDK, not an annotation, so this has to be a custom annotation interface. It uses a common annotation-related class name for an annotation, creating confusion. It uses a long instead of an enum, or at least a declared constant to define a type which is most likely not to be understood as a numeric. And it declares a class name in all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The first two annotations are clearly Java Persistence annotations. There is no JPA or Hibernate annotation **ElementType** so it is not possible to tell from this code snippet what it means.

The fully qualified name for ElementType would provide some more clues, but more than likely this is a custom annotation; the definition of which resides in your code base.